# Как сделать ProgressBar для ffmpeg?

Tags: c#, wpf, ffmpeg, progress-bar

На WPF добавлен ProgressBar

```
<ProgressBar x:Name="progressBar1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="10" Margin="80,160,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="400" Minimum="0" Maximum="100"/>
```

Эта функция нормально перекодирует видео. Но не использует ProgressBar

```
public void StartConvert()
        {
            var waitFlag = true;

            var path_ffmpeg = @"ffmpeg-20161107-34aeb5d-win32-static\bin\ffmpeg.exe";
            var i = @"..\..\";
            var dir_data = new DirectoryInfo(i + @"_data\");
            var fullpath_ffmpeg = dir_data + path_ffmpeg;

            string outfile = " -i \"" + filefullname1 + "\" -codec:v libvpx -crf 10 -b:v 1M -f webm " + filefullname2;

            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
            psi.FileName = filefullname1;
            psi.Arguments = outfile;
            psi.UseShellExecute = true;
            psi.CreateNoWindow = false;


            //
            System.Diagnostics.Process p = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(psi);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);// utput.webm
            //

            p.WaitForExit();
            if (waitFlag)
            {
                p.WaitForExit();
                // wait for exit of called application
            }
        }
```

Это взято с интернета. http://www.freesmartsoft.com/Blog/Review?id=4

```
  private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //StartConvert2();
            StartConvert();
        }
```

**Обновлено**

```
 double duration = 0;
            string outString = null;
            while (!m_streamReader.EndOfStream)
            {
                outString = m_streamReader.ReadLine();
                if ((duration == 0) && outString.Contains("Duration: "))
                {
                    //progress.Report(10);
                    int index = outString.IndexOf(",");
                    TimeSpan span = TimeSpan.Parse(outString.Remove(index).Remove(0, 10).Trim(new char[] { Convert.ToChar(":") }).Trim());
                    duration = span.TotalSeconds;
                }

                // Progress
                if ((duration > 0) && outString.Contains("time="))
                {
                    //progress.Report(50);
                    string startStr = " time=";
                    string stopStr = " bitrate=";

                    int startIndex = outString.IndexOf(startStr);
                    if (startIndex > 0)
                    {
                        int stopIndex = outString.IndexOf(stopStr);
                        string time = outString.Substring(startIndex + startStr.Length, stopIndex - startIndex - startStr.Length);
                        //double progress = 100.0 * double.Parse(time, m_culture.NumberFormat) / progressBar1.Value;
                        var progress2 = 100.0 * double.Parse(time, m_culture.NumberFormat) / duration;

                        m_progress = (int)progress2;

                    }
                }
                progress.Report(m_progress);
               // progress.Report(80);
            }
```

Comment: Судя по коду, он выполняется в GUI-потоке. Нужно вынести его в отдельный поток.

Comment: И вообще, я бы вместо вызова консольного ffmpeg попробовал поискать в [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=ffmpeg) готовую управляемую обёртку.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Задачи требующие долгого ожидания, например какое-то сложное вычисление, или вот как у вас перекодировка видео, должны запускаться в отдельном `Thread` от UI thread. Это позволяет избежать "заморозки" интерфейса, т.е. впечатления, что приложение зависло, а также позволяет с помощью обращения к специальному объекту `Dispatcher` отобразить ход и результат этого сложного и длинного вычисления.

Конкретно по вашему случаю можно сделать следующее:
1) в методе `button_Click` вам нужно воспользоваться специальным классом [`class Progress<T> : IProgress<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Progress%601.%23ctor);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5.2);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true)

```
 var progress = new Progress<int>((p) =>
     {
        progessBar1.Value = p;
     });
```

а метод перекодировки видео следует запустить асинхронно от UI и передать в него инстанс `Progress`, так

```
     try
     {
        //Запускаем асинхронно задачу
        await Task.Run(() => StartConvert2(progress)); // допишите async перед void у button_Click
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Ошибка!");
     }
```

2) в самом методе перекодировки StartConvert2 вы можете изменить значение у прогрессбара вот так `progress.Report(i)` где `i` - это целочисленное значение выражающее процент сделанного.

**`public void StartConvert2(IProgress<int> progress)` в качестве параметра должен быть указан интерфейс, это важно!**

Comment: `public void StartConvert2(Progress<int> progress)`

...

`progress.Report(i)` - Progress<int> не содержит определения для Report

Comment: @codename0082016 Должно быть `public void StartConvert2(IProgress<int> progress)` т.е. тип параметра интерфейс, а не класс.

Comment: @codename0082016 и кнопку запуска выключайте, а после выполнения задачи включайте (в блоке `finally`), чтобы избежать двойного-тройного запуска одной и той же задачи на перекодировку видео.

Comment: `progress2 = 100.0 * double.Parse(time, m_culture.NumberFormat) / progress2;`

Исключение типа "System.FormatException" возникло в mscorlib.dll, но не было обработано в коде пользователя

Дополнительные сведения: Входная строка имела неверный формат.

Comment: а что такое progress2? Из асинхронной задачи нельзя напрямую обращаться к элементам интерфейса, поэтому если у вас происходит попытка деления на значение прогресбара, то действительно будет ошибка. Вы должны в progress только передавать, но не пытаться оттуда что-то получить, сохраняйте во временную переменную прошлое промежуточное решение и потом делите на него.

Comment: (progress2 это duration. -удалено.)

В шапке обновлено.
Теперь не выполняется условие `outString.Contains("Duration: ")` А если убрать это условие то ошибка (отрицательный index = -1) `outString.Remove(index)`