# Как обновлять label и progressbar во время выполнения цикла WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

В общем такая проблема, привязал начало цикла на кнопку обычным образом

```
for (i = 0; i <= 50; ++i)
        {              
            Thread.Sleep(100);       
            label.Content = i.ToString();
        }
```

Но лейбл обновляется только когда цикл достигает конечного числа - 50, как сделать чтобы в лейб последовательно перезаписывались 1, 2, 3, 4... итд. Так же должен заполнятся и прогрессбар.

Но если разберусь с лейблом, то прогрессбар тоже смогу доработать

Comment: Подобный вашему [вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/588904/222542) с ответом

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы делаете обработчик нажатия на кнопку, то советую использовать async/await:

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button.IsEnabled = false;
    for (var i = 0; i <= 50; ++i)
    {
        await Task.Delay(100);
        label.Content = i.ToString();
    }
    Button.IsEnabled = true;
 }
```

Также советую использовать MVVM подход. Для вашей задачи нужно будет разобраться с привязкой к данным и асинхронными командами. Хороший пример по реализации асинхронных команд можно посмотреть [здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/magazine/dn630647.aspx).

Comment: Через backgroundworker реализовывать хотел

Comment: @SOFL backgroundworker => устаревшая технология

Comment: Уточнить тогда можно, то есть backgroundworker/async/await, по сути одно и то же, только async/await более технологически новые и желательные к использованию?

Comment: @SOFL, это не совсем одно и тоже, хотя они и служат одной цели - упрощение жизни программиста при написании асинхронного кода. BackgroundWorker и async/await предлагают разные подходы к организации и написанию асинхронного кода. Подробнее про паттерны асинхронных операций в .NetFramework можно посмотреть [здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/jj152938.aspx). И да, BackgroundWorker считается устаревшим.